# Laravel 5: Apache php http authentication

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I need some help and advice on the following topic.

My boos has a simple Apache server setup and has [a simple php auth](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php)   setup as well. As soon as the user is validated using a panel like this.

[image]

He/she have than access to all the applications running behind it. So in other words this panel serves as a 'gate', if you are over the gate then you have access (of course there is permission table running on the web server).

**Problem**

The App I am building using Laravel 5 needs to run behind the gate, so it means the app needs to know who the user is.

Using `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];` I can fetch the `username` whose currently logged in.

But what if I want to track the `user's` actions on my app? I need something like `$this->user_id` right?

So I was thinking as soon as the user passes the 'gate' I fetch his `username` and create a user out of it saving it in my database running behind Laravel by doing so.

```
  if(isset($_SERVER))
  {
    if ( array_key_exists( 'PHP_AUTH_USER', $_SERVER ) ) {
        $agent = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']; //Request::server('PHP_AUTH_USER')

    }

    $user = User::create([
      'username' => $agent,

      ]);
  }
```

But this makes user every time the user refreshes the page!  But without going further what is the best way to do this?

1. Do I need a separate provider (I tested the code above in `AppServiceProvider`)?
2. How can I do something like this `$this->user_id` after saving the `username`?

**Note**: I know Laravel has basic auth out of box, but this won't work because the user are not yet in my database. I need to create them first just like above.

Comment: How many users will have access to the page? Is it publicly available for any audience or is it an internal page that will be used by N fixed users?

Comment: @lesssugar users inside the company have all access ( of course after you passed login ). It's not publicly accessible from the internet ( if that what you mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should check if a user with the provided username already exists in your database. This way you don't create a new user on every refresh. 
You then can use `Auth::login($user);` to login the user which allows you to use the `auth` middleware provided by Laravel (not `auth.basic`!). This way you can access the user over your entire App with the Auth facade and store additional information about the user:

```php
if(isset($_SERVER))
{
    if ( array_key_exists( 'PHP_AUTH_USER', $_SERVER ) ) {
        $agent = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']; //Request::server('PHP_AUTH_USER')

        // Try to find an existing user, or create a new one if the user does not exist
        $user = User::firstOrCreate([
            'username' => $agent,
        ]);

        // Authenticate the user
        \Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you recommend having the above code in a different provider ( to get only triggered once) or just keep it in `AppServiceProvider`?   Because every time  I run a certain command line I get ErrorException `undefined variable: agent`

Comment: You should place the login code within your second if-statement. I updated my answer accordingly. Artisan shouldn't fail anymore. You can place it inside the AppServiceProvider. I'd move the above code into a dedicated service provider as the application gets bigger. Ultimately, i recommend implementing your own custom Auth provider: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#adding-custom-authentication-drivers

Comment: I have tested this. It only creates one user! so for instance if I log in it creates a user of me (with login username) but if someone else in the company tried to reach the url as well ( I mean logging in ) than it does not create a `user` out of him. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not what you want to hear, but I would really employ Laravel's authentication. Apache basic auth should prevent unauthorized users from accessing your page, and maybe prevent the page from being crawled by bots - not serve as a login form to your app.

Create one set of credentials for Apache auth, so all the people who have it can access the page. But then, create a standard login form with username and password, that will be specific for each user. This way, even is someone manages to get through Apache, they still will not be logged in.

Security-wise, this would be the way to go. Also, doing it this way you open new possibilities: you could store more information about your users, like their preferred language or permissions scope.

Think about it :)

Comment: Thanks for taking time and answering my question. Yes I do have considered your sugessetd option before posting the question. But I need a way-to-go solution and later I will expand it into my separate provider.